# List<Reviews> not updated when a new review is added

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two class: Company and a Review Class.
Company class contains a list Reviews. I have added an end point that add a review which also update the list in the company class. But the thing is that the list is never updated and the navigation property in the class Review is null after adding the review.

The code for the two classes:

```
 public class Company
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CompanyId { get; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string CompanyDescription { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Location { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string City { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Category { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [MaxLength(400)]
        public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
        public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; } = new List<Review>();
    }
```

```
 public class Review
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ReviewId { get; set; }
        [Required,MaxLength(70)]
        public string JobTitle { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required, MaxLength(1000)]
        public string Content { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public DateTime TimeCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
        public int TotalUpvotes { get; set; } = 0;
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

the configuration of the two tables in the OnModelCreating:
for the company table:

```
            builder.HasKey(c => c.CompanyId);

            builder.HasMany(c=>c.Reviews)
                .WithOne(c => c.Company)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyId);
```

for the review table:

```
 builder.HasKey(r => r.ReviewId);
            builder.HasOne(r=>r.User)
                .WithMany(r=>r.Reviews)
                .HasForeignKey(r=>r.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
            builder.HasOne(r => r.Company)
                .WithMany(r => r.Reviews)
                .HasForeignKey(r => r.CompanyId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
```

the service that add a new review:

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<AddReviewResponseDto>> AddReview(AddReviewDto addReviewDto)
ServiceResponse<AddReviewResponseDto> AddReviewResponse = new ServiceResponse<AddReviewResponseDto>();

            //check if the current user is registered in the database
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(GetUserId());

            if (user == null)
            {
                AddReviewResponse.Data = null;
                AddReviewResponse.Success = false;
                AddReviewResponse.Message = "Non Users can't add a review!";
                return AddReviewResponse;
            }

            var company = await _context.Companies.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CompanyId == addReviewDto.CompnayId);
            if (company == null)
            {
                AddReviewResponse.Data = null;
                AddReviewResponse.Success = false;
                AddReviewResponse.Message = "No company was found with this id!";
                return AddReviewResponse;
            }

           
            var review = new Review
            {
                JobTitle = addReviewDto.JobTitle,
                Content = addReviewDto.Content,
                User = user,
                Company = company

            };

            await _context.AddAsync(review);

            company.Reviews.Add(review);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            var addReviewResponseDto = new AddReviewResponseDto
            {
                TimeCreated = review.TimeCreated,
                ReviewId = review.ReviewId
            };

            AddReviewResponse.Data = addReviewResponseDto;
            AddReviewResponse.Success = true;
            AddReviewResponse.Message = "Review was added successfully";
            return AddReviewResponse;

}
```

after execuating the end Point the result is like this:
for the review table:

```
"reviewId": 14,
    "jobTitle": "software engineer",
    "content": "I Love This Company",
    "timeCreated": "2023-03-23T18:54:04.7119397",
    "totalUpvotes": 0,
    "user": null,
    "userId": "userIdvalue",
    "company": null,
    "companyId": 6,
    "upvotes": []
```

for the company table:

```
{
    "companyId": 6,
    "companyName": "Globe Exports",
    "companyDescription": "We Globe exportsare exporters of canned products, pasta, flour, biscuits, jams, honey, tahina, halawa, foul, tomato puree, biscuits, wafer,spices&bean.",
    "location": "Cairo, Egypt",
    "city": "Cairo",
    "category": "Food Industries",
    "photoUrl": "photoUrl",
    "reviewsCount": 0,
    "averageRating": 0,
    "reviews": []
}
```

I have searched a lot and I can't figure out where the problem is?!

Comment: I think Reviews should be declared as `public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews {get;set;}`

Comment: = new List<Review>(); is not needed

Comment: @hijinxbassist the virtual keyword is not needed in Entity Framework Core. That was used to enable lazy-loading via proxy, which was often the cause of inadvertent performance issues (loading a navigation property from the DB while inside a foreach loop). The feature is now not included by default so you have to explicitly opt in

Comment: @Alaa are you including the navigation properties when you load the entities from the database? `_context.Companies.Include(company => company.Reviews).ToListAsync()`

Comment: @Leandro - using `= new List<Review>()` may not be required but is absolutely recommended. This ensures that when instantiating a Company, the Reviews collection is ready to go and not a NullRef. What you want to avoid is any scenario where code does something like `company.Reviews = new List<Review>()`.  Collections should be initialized, Singular navigation properties should never be initialized.

Comment: You have defined the relation between company and review twice (once on each entity configuration). I remember that we had problems with this, so maybe it's a good idea to remove one of them. At least it removes unneeded code.

Comment: @hijinxbassist, I was using eager loading. it was as AndrewWilliamson  and Steve Py have said, I didn't load the reviews using include. Thanks you very much.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson, That was the case!. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JürgenRöhr, I have solved the issue. But just an inquiry, as I want the behavior when deletion of the navigation properties to be different in both tables (CompanyTable: the deleting of reviews will not delete the company related. ReviewTable: deleting of company will delete the review), isn't necessary to define the relation for the two classes?

Comment: @Alaa No, it isn't. You just can't delete the 'master' record by removing the children. Guessing from your naming in the lambdas I assume you might be intrigued by the type of your `builder`s. In the sequence of `Has/WithMany` and `Has/WithOne` you're actually switching between entities. `Has/WithOne` in both definitions takes a navigation expression for `Review` and `Has/WithMany` takes a navigation expression for `Company`. The same is true for `OnDelete`: you always define the action to be executed when deleting a `Company` - even if you'd move it to the configuration of `Review`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you checking that the data does not appear? The code looks fine, though I would say that given you aren't returning any information about the company or review beyond the ID and created timestamp, your code can be simplified slightly. This line is unnecessary:

```
company.Reviews.Add(review);
```

It's relatively harmless in this case, but I would recommend not touching collection properties unless you have eager loaded them.

I don't think there is a problem with the code you have posted, it is probably more of an issue with the code you are using to check the data afterwards. Your Company.Reviews and Review.Company references are not `virtual` so Lazy Loading is off the table which means if you are pulling a Company to inspect all of it's data and associated reviews, you need to eager load them with `Include(x => x.Reveiews)`, same if you pull a Review and want it's Company. Enabling Lazy Loading would allow this data to be filled, but comes with a performance cost which can be significant in some scenarios and it can be problematic with serialization.

So to be clear, the use of `Include` is not necessary in your AddReview method, but rather where you are loading the Company and expecting the reviews to be populated.

If you are checking a database and are not seeing the records being created/associated, then double-check your DbContext's connection string at runtime to ensure it is pointing at the database you expect it to. Quite often a database gets moved or is significant to an environment and the developer updates a local copy of a connection string but at runtime the application is pulling a connection string from a configuration that isn't updated meaning a stale database gets updated while the dev is checking a different database.

Comment: As you said, I didn't use Include when loading the companies. Thank you very much!